# Jenkins trigger another job

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline

i have a pipeline that triggers the same job if it fails. but when the second job is triggered, the first pipeline still stay opened till the second one success or fails, i would like to know if i can close the pipeline after the trigger was made for the second one.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    input message: 'Proceed?', ok: 'Yes', submitter: 'admin'
                }
                echo "helloworld"
            }
            post {
                aborted{
                    script{
                        retry(1) {
                           input "Retry the job ?"
                           build(job: 'pipelines/testCS')
                        }
                    }
                }
                success {
                    script{
                        sh 'echo "continue"'
                    }      
                }
            }            
        }
        stage('deploy'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo "deploy"'
            }
        }

    }
    post {
        aborted {
            echo "pipeline has been aborted"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass `wait: false` for the build step:

```
build(job: 'pipelines/testCS', wait: false)
```

See [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) for all parameters.